# are floating point numbers changed when sorted in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, floating-point

I'm running a statistical bootstrap at 10k permutations, which I'm trying to compare against an observed value. The observed is supposed to be identical to the max of the 10k permutations. The way I am measuring this is by attempting to find its percentile.

All results of the 10k permutations (10,000 random numbers) are stored in an array, which I sort using:

```
my @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} @permutednumbers;
```

When I then compare the observed value `$truevalue`, I'm getting an inaccurate comparison. These are stored as floating point numbers. The bootstrapping procedure uses the same formula for generating the random number so it should be absolutely identical, but when comparing the same value, it becomes inaccurate. I'm testing this with:

```
if ($sorted[$#sorted] == $truevalue) {
  print "sorted: $sorted[$#sorted] is eq truevalue:$truevalue\n";
} elsif ($sorted[$#sorted] > $truevalue) {
  print "sorted: $sorted[$#sorted] is gt truevalue:$truevalue\n";
} elsif ($sorted[$#sorted] < $truevalue) {
   print "sorted: $sorted[$#sorted] is lt truevalue:$truevalue, totalpermvalues; $totalpermvalues\n";
}
```

output:

```
sorted: 0.937864522389543 is gt truevalue:0.937864522389543
```

So I get that floating point numbers aren't printed in complete accuracy, but I always assumed internally the computer stores the correct numbers. Is that not a correct assumption? Of course I can fix this quickly by changing them into integers of some sort, but is this something that I should be doing automatically all the time? Are floating point numbers just dangerous to use? Those exact values should be identical given that they are outputs of identical inputs, which is what is confusing me...

If this matters, the values are individually calculated using the linear_interpolate function in Math::Interpolate package, but the inputs are identical.

Comment: "The bootstrapping procedure uses the same formula for generating the random number so it should be absolutely identical, but when comparing the same value, it becomes inaccurate." Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates this?

Comment: Ok I will try to re-create the problem manually in significantlly less code first and edit my post as soon as possible

Comment: It's not a correct assumption. Floating point numbers are stored as a binary fraction. This leads to rounding errors, and can lead to rounding errors in ways you don't expect. But comparisons should work pretty consistently.

Comment: `$sorted[-1]` is a more concise way of accessing the last element of `@sorted`

Comment: Comparing float point is tricky, but you certainly _cannot_ use `==`.

Comment: "inputs are identical" This may seem so, but marginal differences in floating point numbers can sneak in, depending on whether it is given as a literal in the program or whether the same sequence of numeric characters is read in the input. If you want to get to the bottom of it, use pack to get the bytes of the number's machine representation.

Comment: @zdim Sure you can. `$ perl -e 'print 3.1415926 == 3.1415926'`

Comment: @MattJacob  The question is about comparing them correctly and I am referring to that, "_cannot use_."   Are you raising a point about the language I am using? The question is about the dreadful `x == y` with floating point -- I think that we have to say '_don't do that._'   Please somebody write that nicely and I won't post a thing anymore.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are wondering why `==` is returning false and `>` is returning true for what appear to be identical numbers. Obviously, the numbers are not actually identical. You can see this by printing more digits.

```
printf "sorted: %.80e is gt truevalue:%.80e\n", $sorted[$#sorted], $truevalue;
```

Answer (score 3):

No, sort will not change values. One has to assume that there *is* a difference in the way these two values have been produced.

It is most certainly possible to use `==` with floating point numbers (FPN), returning true if a pair of 64 bit quantities is identical. But one has to be very careful when one ask the question "Are these two FPNs equal?"

A (relatively small but still considerable) quantity of integers and rational numbers can be represented accurately in a FPN. For these (and only for these), questions such as "Is the FPN a *equal* to 1.5?" (written as `$a==1.5`) *may* make sense *but only if you are confident about the genesis of the value* in $a. - Don't take this lightly: will both of the following statements print "1"?

```
print 0.12345678901234567 == 1.2345678901234567E-1,"\n";
print 0.12345678901234567 == 12.345678901234567E-2,"\n";
```

All FPNs are not only representatives of the value *x* they represent accurately. They are also responsible for an *interval* of real numbers, including rational, irrational and transcendent (and even integer) numbers "a little greater and a little smaller" than *x*. You can quantify "a little": it is 1e-16 for x == 1.0, and shrinks or grows accordingly. So, for instance, 1+1e-17 will be 1.0 on your computer. You can input this number, but the FPN will be 1.0 all the same. Asking whether a FPN as the result of some computation equals 1+1e-17 doesn't make sense since you cannot even tell the computer that value.

The solution isn't difficult. Instead of asking for equality you have to ask "Is the FPN *a* in an interval [*p*,*q*] around x?" Determining *p* and *q* should be given a little thought, as a suitable choice of these values primarily depends on *x*. The usual formula is something like

```
abs( $a - $expect ) <= $expect*PRECISION
```

where `PRECISION` could be, for instance, 1e-12. (The value to use here may depend on the algorithm you use for computing `$a`, or on your needs, or both.)

Finally: due to the mathematical properties of FP machine instructions, the usual arithmetic laws of associativity or distributivity are not guaranteed. The effect of truncation in addition or subtraction may, for instance cause heavy distortion in the result. A typical example for illustrating this, compute some Taylor series: once adding terms in decreasing order until terms become smaller than a given limit, and once, using the same terms, but in increasing order.

Comment: Re "No, sort will not change values", unless the numbers were initially strings.

Comment: @ikegami After `@a = sort {$a<=>$b}("12.34000", "+45.67"); `, the resulting list prints as `12.34000+45.67`, as opposed to the result of `map( 0+$_,(...))`. Clearly, for the sort, it has to be converted to numeric, but is this the issue discussed here?

Comment: It might be. The OP provided so little info.